# How do I get my cat, who doesn't let me hold her, to the Vet?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, animal-handling

My rescue will probably never let me hold her - no clue why - but how am I going to get her into her carrier and take her to the Vet?  I'm a senior and live alone and she's 15lbs (7 kg).  She is always either near me or on my lap or next to me in bed.  I just can't pick her up without seeing a nasty side of her. :-(

Comment: Can you give more information on how she reacts when you pick her up? Is she just very squirmy, does she bite or scratch, does she hiss or otherwise vocalize?

Comment: She is all legs, crying that angry fighting scream, no hissing and I let her go before any biting or scratching but I believe she would if I didn't let her go.  She is such a lover and follows me around.  She is between 2 and 6 according to the shelter but I think closer to 2.  She appears to have had a litter at some time.  She is an inside cat and doesn't seem to have any desire to go outside.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. I linked you to a very similar question that already has several answers. Some of them don't need you to pick the cat up at all, but require some training. You train that the carrier is not a scary place, but a comfortable place to sleep or a place where some tasty treat can be found. Then, when you need to go to the vet, you simply close the door and don't have to fight the cat to get her in there.